# Navigation Drawer not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, drawerlayout

I'm really confused about how can I implement the navigation sidebar in my app, yet I already tried it but it conflicts and it tears down my design `XML` if I've implemented it. The conflict is when I change my `constraintLayout` to `DrawLayout` under `activity_main` my design will tear down but when implementing navigation sidebar I need to use `DrawLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`

**Fist Image** is the main `XML` the normal UI , the **Second image** describes the output when I tried to change my `constraintlayout` to `drawerlayout` in my `activity main`, some design didn't showed up, but the navigation sidebar works well like in the **Third image**. The question is it is possible to use `constraintlayout` instead of `drawerlayout` ? to avoid tearing down the UI design? or maybe there is other way to view the design using `drawerLayout`.

[image: Firstimage]
[image]
[image]

**Activitymain.xml** This is what I used in second Image using `drawerlayout` The navigation sidebar works well in this but the design teared down. but when I used `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`  constraintlayout the UI layout will not tear down but it conflicts and the app crashed because in the `MainActivity` it using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` . I hope anyone can help me with this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigationview"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/sidebar_header"
    app:menu="@menu/sidemenu"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="Toolbars"
    app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:titleMarginStart = "10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>


<View
    android:id="@+id/viewHeaderBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_125sdp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
    style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.Circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:SpinKit_Color="@color/validation"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:text="Cash Grants"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_26sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_26sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/dswd_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textTitle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textTitle"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    />


<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_16sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewHeaderBackground"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewHeaderBackground">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/_14sdp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overview"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/textViews"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutClients"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutImpacted"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clients"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Sync"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutImpacted"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutFollowing"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutClients"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_impacted"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Pending"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPending"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutFollowing"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutImpacted"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_following"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Spam"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardHeader">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_1"/>
        <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_2"/>
        <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_3"/>
        <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    
</ScrollView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawerlayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerlayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_open,R.string.navigation_close);
    drawerlayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is it is possible to use constraintlayout instead of drawerlayout

Yes it is.

You just need to make sure that your design skeleton looks like:

```
<DrawerLayout>

    <NavigationView>

    <!--Main layout-->
    <ConstraintLayout>
         <view1 inside ConstraintLayout>
         <view2 inside ConstraintLayout>
         ....
```

But what you did is that you replaced the `ConstraintLayout` with `DrawerLayout` so that the views could't be properly laid out with the unknown constraints:

```
<DrawerLayout>

    <NavigationView>

    <view1 inside ConstraintLayout>
    <view2 inside ConstraintLayout>
    ....
```

So, applying that in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationview"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/sidebar_header"
        app:menu="@menu/sidemenu"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:title="Toolbars"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:titleMarginStart = "10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewHeaderBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_125sdp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
            style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.Circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:SpinKit_Color="@color/validation"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:text="Cash Grants"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_26sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_26sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/dswd_logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textTitle"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/cardHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_16sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewHeaderBackground"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewHeaderBackground">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/_14sdp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Overview"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/textViews"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutClients"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutImpacted"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_clients"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="Sync"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutImpacted"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutFollowing"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutClients"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_impacted"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="Pending"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPending"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutFollowing"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutImpacted"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViews">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_following"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="Spam"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardHeader">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_1"/>
                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_2"/>
                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_3"/>
                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_item_4"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            
        </ScrollView>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```